# Android Flip Animation Grow and fade in from around , shrink and fade out to around?

Tags: android, android-animation, flip

I want to make a flip animation where one image will grow from around and it will shrink to one point. During growing it will be fade in and when shrink it will be fade out.  I have tried many xml code but exactly this kind of code still unavailable to me.

For example, here is an example of what I've tried. It is growing from around but not fading in.

```
<scale
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
  android:fromXScale="1.4"
  android:toXScale="0.0"
  android:fromYScale="1.4"
  android:toYScale="0.0"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:fillAfter="false"
  android:duration="1000"
/>
```

Comment: You should elaborate your problem. What do you mean by growing and shrinking in context of images.

Comment: That means it will appear from around and disable to around.

Comment: Around.? You said *I have tried many xml code*. Can you post what you have tried. that will simplify the task.

Comment: Flip as in you rotate a business card vertically ? That would be a horizontal scale animation plus a fade animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 animation sets for that.

Animation set 1 will be for Scaling up and Fade in.

After animationSet1 is ended, start animation set 2

Animation set 2 will be for Shrinking and Fade out.